# Install Windows on laptop using HP-provided License Key

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I have an HP (dv6 6119tx) laptop which came with Windows 7 Home Premium (64Bit) pre-installed, I have a factory provided recovery partition (13GB) which recovers Windows, drivers and crapware I don't need. I have a label (sort of sticker) attached at the bottom of my laptop which has License key for Windows 7 Home Premium imprint on it.

Now, I don't want to keep that recovery partition so that I can use those precious 13 GB for my data, so can I use Windows Install (official Microsoft provided ISO) disk to install Win7 Home Premium (32 or 64 bit) using that license key on sticker (I'm aware of the facts like I can't use that license on more than 1 computer, etc. etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can - with earlier versions, you'd have to have the specific SKU (so an OEM disk for OEM - i frequently use sticker keys off white box systems and do clean installs with systembuilder OEM disks), but with windows 7 apparently all discs are the same other than the [ei.cfg file](http://windows7center.com/news/how-to-install-any-version-or-sku-of-windows-7/), which merely determines the version. Its also hinted that phone activation *may* be needed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-oem-key-with-a-non-oem-disc/7788dfa2-94a7-4db3-8bcd-b0e109bd7b95?page=1).

Comment: +1 Did this on an HP desktop and had no issue.  Did same on a dell and I had to call MS but no real issue